# Understanding CrashLogs

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, debugging

I just submitted my first app to the App Store and got a rejection together with the following crash log. I don't really understand what do. Apple says I have to symbolize the report and replace the hexadecimal addresses. However, I feel this crash log looks different from the examples I have seen so far. Also I can't reproduce this error on the corresponding simulator or the physical device I have (different from the one in the crash log)

I don't really know how to proceed now. Any advise would be highly appreciated !

Thank you!

```
{"app_name":"QUESTI","timestamp":"2021-10-03 11:47:48.00 -0700","app_version":"1.2","slice_uuid":"c4d330dd-981d-3230-8a4a-3f36d023e0b5","adam_id":"1587893969","build_version":"3","platform":2,"bundleID":"question.io","share_with_app_devs":0,"is_first_party":0,"bug_type":"309","os_version":"iPhone OS 15.0 (19A346)","incident_id":"24AA73BC-C05B-41D7-91AE-3172D5E27382","name":"Questi"}
{
  "uptime" : 430000,
  "procLaunch" : "2021-10-03 11:47:45.7420 -0700",
  "procRole" : "Foreground",
  "version" : 2,
  "userID" : 501,
  "deployVersion" : 210,
  "modelCode" : "iPad7,5",
  "procStartAbsTime" : 10522909165176,
  "coalitionID" : 2522,
  "osVersion" : {
    "isEmbedded" : true,
    "train" : "iPhone OS 15.0",
    "releaseType" : "User",
    "build" : "19A346"
  },
  "captureTime" : "2021-10-03 11:47:48.2928 -0700",
  "incident" : "24AA73BC-C05B-41D7-91AE-3172D5E27382",
  "bug_type" : "309",
  "pid" : 9289,
  "procExitAbsTime" : 10522970280677,
  "cpuType" : "ARM-64",
  "procName" : "CityQuest",
  "procPath" : "\/private\/var\/containers\/Bundle\/Application\/1B49320E-517F-4755-801C-684B9E007BEA\/Questi.app\/Questi",
  "bundleInfo" : {"CFBundleShortVersionString":"1.2","CFBundleVersion":"3","CFBundleIdentifier":"Questi.io","DTAppStoreToolsBuild":"13A227"},
  "storeInfo" : {"itemID":"1587893969","deviceIdentifierForVendor":"CF09D7BD-0A17-4748-9F3D-EA409B835C0A","thirdParty":true,"softwareVersionExternalIdentifier":"844357786"},
  "parentProc" : "launchd",
  "parentPid" : 1,
  "coalitionName" : "Questi.io",
  "crashReporterKey" : "46ea00953c64e34e6e1d4681e4c11ec9b0464884",
  "isCorpse" : 1,
  "exception" : {"codes":"0x0000000000000001, 0x0000000100205ef0","rawCodes":[1,4297088752],"type":"EXC_BREAKPOINT","signal":"SIGTRAP"},
  "termination" : {"flags":0,"code":5,"namespace":"SIGNAL","indicator":"Trace\/BPT trap: 5","byProc":"exc handler","byPid":9289},
  "ktriageinfo" : "VM - Fault hit memory shortage\nVM - Fault hit memory shortage\nVM - Fault hit memory shortage\nVM - Fault hit memory shortage\nVM - Fault hit memory shortage\n",
  "faultingThread" : 0,
  "threads" : [{"triggered":true,"id":2347984,"threadState":{"x":[{"value":10745873440},{"value":8},{"value":4297142032},{"value":16},{"value":112},{"value":16},{"value":112},{"value":0},{"value":4},{"value":35184372088832},{"value":76557804892205},{"value":0},{"value":8406400},{"value":8333411440},{"value":9005137670438912},{"value":8333411440},{"value":6885815328},{"value":6496201196},{"value":0},{"value":4318104752},{"value":0},{"value":10758396144},{"value":10745873440},{"value":4611686029216340448},{"value":16645304222761353216},{"value":8420947448},{"value":10781696512},{"value":10803701024},{"value":10758396144}],"flavor":"ARM_THREAD_STATE64","lr":{"value":4297088124},"cpsr":{"value":536870912},"fp":{"value":6169880096},"sp":{"value":6169880016},"esr":{"value":4060086273,"description":"(Breakpoint) brk 1"},"pc":{"value":4297088752,"matchesCrashFrame":1},"far":{"value":4306510864}},"queue":"com.apple.main-thread","frames":[{"imageOffset":89840,"imageIndex":0},{"imageOffset":89212,"imageIndex":0},{"imageOffset":87824,"imageIndex":0},{"imageOffset":102116,"imageIndex":0},{"imageOffset":497848,"imageIndex":0},{"imageOffset":418800,"imageIndex":0},{"imageOffset":406252,"imageIndex":1},{"imageOffset":410352,"imageIndex":1},{"imageOffset":68000,"imageIndex":1},{"imageOffset":317432,"imageIndex":2},{"imageOffset":45304,"imageIndex":2},{"imageOffset":122252,"imageIndex":2},{"imageOffset":6560,"imageIndex":3},{"imageOffset":5169176,"imageIndex":4},{"imageOffset":2630300,"imageIndex":4},{"imageOffset":163456,"imageIndex":5},{"imageOffset":31192,"imageIndex":0},{"imageOffset":98704,"imageIndex":6}]},{"id":2348014,"frames":[{"imageOffset":2716,"imageIndex":7}]},{"id":2348015,"frames":[{"imageOffset":2716,"imageIndex":7}]},{"id":2348016,"frames":[{"imageOffset":2716,"imageIndex":7}]},{"id":2348017,"frames":[{"imageOffset":2716,"imageIndex":7}]},{"id":2348018,"name":"com.apple.uikit.eventfetch-thread","frames":[{"imageOffset":2928,"imageIndex":8},{"imageOffset":4500,"imageIndex":8},{"imageOffset":27344,"imageIndex":2},{"imageOffset":43960,"imageIndex":2},{"imageOffset":122252,"imageIndex":2},{"imageOffset":97132,"imageIndex":9},{"imageOffset":355692,"imageIndex":9},{"imageOffset":4635072,"imageIndex":4},{"imageOffset":411212,"imageIndex":9},{"imageOffset":9304,"imageIndex":7},{"imageOffset":2736,"imageIndex":7}]},{"id":2348019,"frames":[{"imageOffset":2716,"imageIndex":7}]},{"id":2348020,"frames":[{"imageOffset":2716,"imageIndex":7}]},{"id":2348025,"frames":[{"imageOffset":2716,"imageIndex":7}]},{"id":2348027,"frames":[{"imageOffset":2716,"imageIndex":7}]},{"id":2348028,"frames":[{"imageOffset":2716,"imageIndex":7}]},{"id":2348029,"frames":[{"imageOffset":2716,"imageIndex":7}]},{"id":2348031,"name":"com.apple.NSURLConnectionLoader","frames":[{"imageOffset":2928,"imageIndex":8},{"imageOffset":4500,"imageIndex":8},{"imageOffset":27344,"imageIndex":2},{"imageOffset":43960,"imageIndex":2},{"imageOffset":122252,"imageIndex":2},{"imageOffset":2408760,"imageIndex":10},{"imageOffset":411212,"imageIndex":9},{"imageOffset":9304,"imageIndex":7},{"imageOffset":2736,"imageIndex":7}]},{"id":2348032,"name":"com.squareup.SocketRocket.NetworkThread","frames":[{"imageOffset":2928,"imageIndex":8},{"imageOffset":4500,"imageIndex":8},{"imageOffset":27344,"imageIndex":2},{"imageOffset":43960,"imageIndex":2},{"imageOffset":122252,"imageIndex":2},{"imageOffset":97132,"imageIndex":9},{"imageOffset":697612,"imageIndex":0},{"imageOffset":411212,"imageIndex":9},{"imageOffset":9304,"imageIndex":7},{"imageOffset":2736,"imageIndex":7}]},{"id":2348054,"name":"com.apple.CFSocket.private","frames":[{"imageOffset":6012,"imageIndex":8},{"imageOffset":665356,"imageIndex":2},{"imageOffset":9304,"imageIndex":7},{"imageOffset":2736,"imageIndex":7}]}],
  "usedImages" : [
  {
    "source" : "P",
    "arch" : "arm64",
    "base" : 4296998912,
    "size" : 9076736,
    "uuid" : "c4d330dd-981d-3230-8a4a-3f36d023e0b5",
    "path" : "\/private\/var\/containers\/Bundle\/Application\/1B49320E-517F-4755-801C-684B9E007BEA\/Questi.app\/Questi",
    "name" : "Questi"
  },
  {
    "source" : "P",
    "arch" : "arm64",
    "base" : 6495793152,
    "size" : 536576,
    "uuid" : "5d722afc-fb8c-3769-bf66-167bb94a6133",
    "path" : "\/usr\/lib\/system\/libdispatch.dylib",
    "name" : "libdispatch.dylib"
  },
  {
    "source" : "P",
    "arch" : "arm64",
    "base" : 6498963456,
    "size" : 4435968,
    "uuid" : "fe94d75f-5f1d-3127-ba50-0161d8817ee6",
    "path" : "\/System\/Library\/Frameworks\/CoreFoundation.framework\/CoreFoundation",
    "name" : "CoreFoundation"
  },
  {
    "source" : "P",
    "arch" : "arm64",
    "base" : 6936387584,
    "size" : 36864,
    "uuid" : "87b24bb5-a3dd-358d-9abb-a1f70544a383",
    "path" : "\/System\/Library\/PrivateFrameworks\/GraphicsServices.framework\/GraphicsServices",
    "name" : "GraphicsServices"
  },
  {
    "source" : "P",
    "arch" : "arm64",
    "base" : 6536077312,
    "size" : 24674304,
    "uuid" : "3f83ef9a-7492-3fec-a486-5fc2a1e1b092",
    "path" : "\/System\/Library\/PrivateFrameworks\/UIKitCore.framework\/UIKitCore",
    "name" : "UIKitCore"
  },
  {
    "source" : "P",
    "arch" : "arm64",
    "base" : 6870159360,
    "size" : 389120,
    "uuid" : "6559dd65-5a4c-38ee-a095-c798ca99c900",
    "path" : "\/usr\/lib\/swift\/libswiftUIKit.dylib",
    "name" : "libswiftUIKit.dylib"
  },
  {
    "source" : "P",
    "arch" : "arm64",
    "base" : 4310401024,
    "size" : 344064,
    "uuid" : "d7a0282e-93de-3a1e-9813-27e84517cc96",
    "path" : "\/usr\/lib\/dyld",
    "name" : "dyld"
  },
  {
    "source" : "P",
    "arch" : "arm64",
    "base" : 7987109888,
    "size" : 65536,
    "uuid" : "c685b493-59ff-3f13-a9b3-3d3bb868ccd5",
    "path" : "\/usr\/lib\/system\/libsystem_pthread.dylib",
    "name" : "libsystem_pthread.dylib"
  },
  {
    "source" : "P",
    "arch" : "arm64",
    "base" : 7448956928,
    "size" : 204800,
    "uuid" : "83a7e955-4c94-3d9d-9c11-63fe9c36fbd7",
    "path" : "\/usr\/lib\/system\/libsystem_kernel.dylib",
    "name" : "libsystem_kernel.dylib"
  },
  {
    "source" : "P",
    "arch" : "arm64",
    "base" : 6523363328,
    "size" : 3010560,
    "uuid" : "b17c0d3b-cabb-3212-9056-0791b2521900",
    "path" : "\/System\/Library\/Frameworks\/Foundation.framework\/Foundation",
    "name" : "Foundation"
  },
  {
    "source" : "P",
    "arch" : "arm64",
    "base" : 6507163648,
    "size" : 4808704,
    "uuid" : "f7a43d65-fd8d-370a-bc3c-300718fa502c",
    "path" : "\/System\/Library\/Frameworks\/CFNetwork.framework\/CFNetwork",
    "name" : "CFNetwork"
  }
],
  "sharedCache" : {
  "base" : 6495485952,
  "size" : 2190065664,
  "uuid" : "06fe3f75-1833-3ca2-ae2e-f5881530aa7d"
},
  "vmSummary" : "ReadOnly portion of Libraries: Total=690.8M resident=0K(0%) swapped_out_or_unallocated=690.8M(100%)\nWritable regions: Total=552.0M written=0K(0%) resident=0K(0%) swapped_out=0K(0%) unallocated=552.0M(100%)\n\n                                VIRTUAL   REGION \nREGION TYPE                        SIZE    COUNT (non-coalesced) \n===========                     =======  ======= \nActivity Tracing                   256K        1 \nCG raster data                     512K       16 \nColorSync                           64K        4 \nCoreAnimation                       96K        4 \nFoundation                          16K        1 \nKernel Alloc Once                   32K        1 \nMALLOC                           542.2M       41 \nMALLOC guard page                  192K       12 \nSQLite page cache                  320K        5 \nSTACK GUARD                        240K       15 \nStack                             8624K       15 \nVM_ALLOCATE                        160K        2 \n__DATA                            19.1M      555 \n__DATA_CONST                      48.1M      567 \n__DATA_DIRTY                      2005K      465 \n__FONT_DATA                          4K        1 \n__LINKEDIT                       182.4M       13 \n__OBJC_RO                         89.7M        1 \n__OBJC_RW                         3328K        1 \n__TEXT                           508.5M      582 \n__UNICODE                          588K        1 \ndyld private memory               1424K       18 \nlibnetwork                         128K        8 \nmapped file                      156.3M        9 \nshared memory                       48K        3 \n===========                     =======  ======= \nTOTAL                              1.5G     2341 \n",
  "legacyInfo" : {
  "threadTriggered" : {
    "queue" : "com.apple.main-thread"
  }
},
  "trialInfo" : {
  "rollouts" : [
    {
      "rolloutId" : "60da5e84ab0ca017dace9abf",
      "factorPackIds" : {

      },
      "deploymentId" : 240000008
    },
    {
      "rolloutId" : "607844aa04477260f58a8077",
      "factorPackIds" : {
        "SIRI_MORPHUN_ASSETS" : "6103050cbfe6dc472e1c982a"
      },
      "deploymentId" : 240000066
    },
    {
      "rolloutId" : "5ffde50ce2aacd000d47a95f",
      "factorPackIds" : {

      },
      "deploymentId" : 240000042
    },
    {
      "rolloutId" : "601d9415f79519000ccd4b69",
      "factorPackIds" : {
        "SIRI_TEXT_TO_SPEECH" : "6152c915f387f92b1fffc0a6"
      },
      "deploymentId" : 240000228
    },
    {
      "rolloutId" : "60509d56f2766876dee21c11",
      "factorPackIds" : {
        "SIRI_UNDERSTANDING_MORPHUN" : "6152c749f387f92b1fffc029"
      },
      "deploymentId" : 240000431
    },
    {
      "rolloutId" : "5fc94383418129005b4e9ae0",
      "factorPackIds" : {

      },
      "deploymentId" : 240000134
    },
    {
      "rolloutId" : "602c34a3046661000c9ebdde",
      "factorPackIds" : {

      },
      "deploymentId" : 240000437
    },
    {
      "rolloutId" : "602ad4dac86151000cf27e46",
      "factorPackIds" : {
        "SIRI_DICTATION_ASSETS" : "6152c7f241685658846fb273"
      },
      "deploymentId" : 240000216
    }
  ],
  "experiments" : [

  ]
}
}
´´´
```

Comment: That's not a human readable crash log.

Comment: That's not the normal crashlog that you get, however, looking through what is there it looks like a memory exhaustion issue and I see a reference to the websocket library you are using. Possibly your app goes into an invite loop and consumes all available memory before crashing if there is a network connectivity problem.  Have you tested your app on a real device, using a TestFlight build, on an IPv6 network. With no network connectivity etc. ?

Answer (score 0):

I’ve found that sometimes when I try to symbolicate the crash log that Apple provides, I run into issues. Many times I’ve had no issues on my end, however once tested, they crash during App Store review.

The easiest way I have come across to find out what’s going on is to upload the app to TestFlight and let it run on your device. It will crash and then you can view the symbolicated crash log through Xcode for your device. Open the log with Xcode and it will take you the line where the app crashed.